# package conflict between heroku and elasticsearch dsl

Tags: python, elasticsearch, heroku, django-rest-framework, elasticsearch-dsl

I am working in my school project using djangorestframework. I got a conflict error while deploying my project in heroku. Heroku depends on python-dateutil version 1.5. But elasticsearch dsl uses newer version of python-dateutil package. So i get error while deploying. If i use python-dateutil package of 1.5, i get error in release phase due to elasticsearch. If i use newer version i get error in build phase due to heroku. Any solution? plzz help me

Error when using python-dateutil package 1.5
.........................................
.........................................
File "C:\Users\karun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch_dsl\document.py", line 30, in 
from .field import Field
File "C:\Users\karun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch_dsl\field.py", line 29, in 
from dateutil import parser, tz
File "C:\Users\karun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 158
l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Error while using newer python-dateutil package

The conflict is caused by:
The user requested python-dateutil==2.8.2
elasticsearch-dsl 7.4.0 depends on python-dateutil
heroku 0.1.4 depends on python-dateutil==1.5

```
   To fix this you could try to:
   1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
   2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
   
   ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0):

The [`heroku` module on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/heroku/) is *ancient* and [abandoned](https://github.com/heroku/heroku.py). [Its last release was in 2013](https://pypi.org/project/heroku/#history).

The similarly ancient version of `python-dateutil` upon which it depends uses deprecated, Python 2-only syntax for for `repr`: literal backticks. [It won't work on Python 3](https://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html?highlight=backtick#to3fixer-repr).

I'm not sure why you installed `heroku`, but you definitely don't need it. Remove it from your dependencies, commit, and redeploy.